# How to make a sprite have autonomy?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a question about the movement of sprites autonomously, that is to say that from certain conditions are mobilized on the map in the simplest and most optimal way possible.

Let's say I have a Phaser.Group of 7 sprites that move in a labyrinth (TileMap) and must cross it, not necessarily to reach a specific target (like the ghosts of Pacman) but when they reach a crossroads choose a path to random. I do this in the following way: In *update()* I call a function *"mobilizeSprite()"* and this function contains a ForEach loop that runs throughout the group, inside the loop I must compare the coordinates of the sprite with those of an array and if they are in this one Then it means that in this positions you can choose a random path (up, down, left or right) but then it goes its previous way.

Is my code really optimal? Because if I add more sprites to the group then the consumption will be much greater and this does it in the function *update ()*, Is there an easier way ?. I was thinking of adding a timer to each sprite (like a scheduler) bypassing the ForEach, however I do not know if that's possible.

Here the code:

```
...
update: function() {
        movilizeSprite();
}
...
mobilizeSprite: function() {
        this._enemies.forEach(function(enemy) {

                if (enemy.name == 'ship') {
                    var position = Math.round(enemy.body.x)+','+Math.round(enemy.body.y),
                        index = this._crossroads.indexOf(position);

                    if ((index != -1 && index % 2 == 0) || enemy.body.speed == 0) {
                        enemy.body.velocity.x = 0;
                        enemy.body.velocity.y = 0;
                        this._movements[this.rnd.integerInRange(0, (this._movements.length-1))](enemy);
                    }
                }
        }, this);
}
```

**this._movements:** It is an array with four functions, each one receives as a parameter the sprite and mobilizes it, if the index is 0 then it mobilizes it to the right, if it is 1 then moves it to the left, etc ...

**this._crossroads:** It is an array with the coordinates of all crossroads and waypoints, this arrangement is essential to know if the sprite can take another path. The problem is that the positions of the crossroads are in even indices (x % 2): *0, 2, 4, 6...*

Comment: This question is better suited to [Stack Exchange Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)